# Determine the correct solutions for three circles intersection

Tags: math, intersection, geometry

I have three intersecting circles with inaccurate radii. How can I determine three out of six intersection points which form the intersection area? I was initially thinking of simply getting the cluster points - points which have smallest distances between them. But since the radii are not always correct, there might be cases where the cluster points are not the points forming the intersection area. Any ideas?

[image: circles]

Comment: What do you mean by "inaccurate radii" -- that you know their values with some nonzero uncertainty?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate more on the "inaccuracy" problem. I don't see how it is relevant or what it means (for example, even without any "inaccuracy" the three closest-together intersection points may not be the right ones. Look at your picture!)

Comment: My picture is an example of why I can't simply determine the cluster points by calculating their distance. Ideally, the cluster points would be located close to each other, but since I don't know the correct radii (I estimate the radii based on a parameter, hence they might be inaccurate), the cluster points are not the one forming the intersection area. I hope I explain it a bit clearly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each pair of circles, find the two intersections (if they exist) on their boundary.  Then test to see if one of these points is inside the third circle (distance to the center less than the radius of that circle).

This will identify the three "corner" points of the region of triple intersection, at least when such an intersection exists.

By the way, the intersection of two circles is really more of a linear problem than a quadratic one, properly approached.

Comment: @printemps, What do you do when A's radius is smaller than it should be? Then there is no enclosed region where a human would declare the "intersection", but there is still a reasonable region to declare as the intersection. See http://tinypic.com/r/5wqia/6 - here the "approximate intersection" I'd say should be somewhere in the red area.